# FormData is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, constructor

I'm trying to make a ajax request to upload a image. My problem is when I create the **FormData**. My console is saying "dataForm is not a constructor".

How can I solve this ?

here is my script

```
$("#new-broadcast-image-static").on("change", function(formData) {
                var formData = new formData();

                // line that console point the error //
                var file = $("#new-broadcast-image-static")[0].files[0];
                formData.set("image", file);

                $.ajax({
                    url: apiUrl + "image/upload",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        hashNewBroadcastImage = data.data.identifier;
                        $("#hash-new-broadcast-image-static").val(hashNewBroadcastImage);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: What do you think the callback for `.on()` gives? The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says it passes the event as the first parameter. It's not something you can execute.

Comment: What browser are you using? check this link for compatible browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic because this was just a typo.

Answer (score 8):

Capitalize it: `var formData = new FormData();`

But what are you trying to acomplish anyways? You are reasigning a variable you are getting as parameter:

```
 $("#new-broadcast-image-static").on("change", function(formData) {
      var formData = new formData();
```

You probably want to change it to something like

```
 $("#new-broadcast-image-static").on("change", function(e) {
      var formData = new FormData();
```

Answer (score 6):

Not totally sure about it, but I think you have a capital letter mistake, you've write formData() instead of FormData()

The correct way:

```
var formData = new FormData();
```

Answer (score 4):

---

> Please Check this Possibility it will definitely solve your problem

---

Anywhere in your JS Code if you are assigning a value to FormData like below

```
FormData={"PersonID":1,"PersonName":"Test"};
```

and if you use like this

```
var a = new FormData();
```

Then it will throw an error like "*FormData is not a constructor as it is already declared as an Object*".

Comment: I also made same mistake. I already declared an array with name FormData. Below that i was declaring FormData()

Answer (score 0):

as my experience sometime because of in javascript function is debugger mode.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the solutions for this and none worked. After hours of pulling my hair out, I discovered it was because I had a filed named FormData, which was a partial Vue Pinia State. I changed the name of that file to formData and it worked. So if you run into this problem and can't solve it and you have FormData used as a variable or file name anywhere in your project - change it and see if that fixes it.